# How to embed or recreate a Google Analytics Graph in a custom CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I would like to know how to create a graph with Google Analytics (maybe using the api), but I'm unsure if there is already a plugin or tutorial on how to do this. The Javascript API reference at Google.com sucks.

Also any reference to how to create a line graph (canvas element?) would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: i was unable to follow Google's Javascript API reference, as well. I found the tutorial at NetTuts+ to be excellent: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-graphs-with-google-chart-tools/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I learned to use the Google Visualization API (the one used by analytics, and the one I believe you refer to) from the examples at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs and found it quite clear.

You can use examples of different graphs from the Gallery as well: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html

Answer (score 2):

I created a service specifically for this purpose:
[EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com)

You define your chart type (line, bar, horizontal bar), metrics (pageviews, visits, etc), dimension (date, country,etc), and a time frame.  Then you simply embed a snippet of code into your site where you want the chart to appear.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a commercial solution, but this is great! Thanks for your great work.

Answer (score 2):

Google now has an article specifically on this topic. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts

Comment: Two important files, https://code.google.com/p/ga-api-javascript-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/analyticsCharts/analyticsCharts.js and https://code.google.com/p/ga-api-javascript-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/analyticsCharts/analyticsCharts.html are missing.  Anyone knows where to get them?  Thanks.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/vietutd-js/downloads/detail?name=analyticsCharts.js&can=2&q=

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Google Analytics Easy Dashboard Javascript Library**

An easy way to build a custom Google Analytics Dashboard on your own page.

http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html#register

Demo: http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/demos/set-demo.html

Comment: Thanks... but this seems to work only for users that have been authorized with GA access. so not a public access graph :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is step-by-step guide how to embed Google Analytics chart into a webpage as interactive widget: http://explainum.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-add-google-analytics-chart-to.html

EDIT (5/15/2012): The link above goes to a blog post on Explainum -- 3rd party web-service which allows creating embeddable charts from various data sources including (and most popular) Google Analytics.

Connection to GA is made using OAuth. You will need to know your GA profile ID in order to connect. Data is updated every 2-24 hours. The service is free.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of Explainum's creators.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.